# MS Access VBA export table to text file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the code below to export data from Access table to text file so i can use it in mySQL.

My export code:

```
Sub ExpTblCity()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
Dim t, sText, rText, LResult As String

Close #1
t = "INSERT INTO `tblcity` (`city_id`,`city_name`,`city_enabled`) VALUES "

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Open Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\2-TblCity.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, t

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCity", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
rText = "'NULL'"
sText = "('" & rst!CityID & "','" & rst!City & "','0'),"

LResult = Replace(sText, rText, "NULL")
    Print #1, LResult
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

t = ""
sText = ""
rText = ""
LResult = ""

Close #1

Exit_This_Sub:
    Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
    If Err = 0 Then
    ElseIf Err = 94 Then
        Resume Next
    ElseIf Err = 3265 Then
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    End If
Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub
```

Output from the above code:

```
INSERT INTO `tblcity` (`city_id`,`city_name`,`city_enabled`) VALUES 
('1','London','0'),
('2','Paris','0'),
('3','Rome','0'),
('4','Athens','0'),
('5','Madrit','0'),
```

The code is working fine BUT i am trying to replace IN THE LAST ROW the last **,** with **;**.

Correct output:

```
...
('4','Athens','0'),
('5','Madrit','0');
```

Any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be convenient to save it by using an array and use the Join Function.

```
Sub ExpTblCity()
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim t As String, sText As String, rText As String, LResult As String
    Dim vResult() As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Close #1
    t = "INSERT INTO `tblcity` (`city_id`,`city_name`,`city_enabled`) VALUES "
    
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    
    Open Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\2-TblCity.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, t
    
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCity", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        n = n + 1
        rText = "'NULL'"
        sText = "('" & rst!CityID & "','" & rst!City & "','0')"
        ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To n)
        
        sText = Replace(sText, rText, "NULL")
         vResult(n) = sText
        'Print #1, LResult
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    sText = Join(vResult, "," & vbCrLf) & ";"
    Print #1, sText
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    
    t = ""
    sText = ""
    rText = ""
    LResult = ""
    
    Close #1
    
Exit_This_Sub:
        Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
        If Err = 0 Then
        ElseIf Err = 94 Then
            Resume Next
        ElseIf Err = 3265 Then
            Resume Next
        Else
            MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        End If
    Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Code inside loop to convert 'Null' to NULL. `n = n + 1`   `rText = "'NULL'"`   `sText = "('" & rst!CityID & "','" & rst!City & "','0')"`   `ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To n)`   `LResult = Replace(sText, rText, "NULL")`   `vResult(n) = LResult`   `rst.MoveNext`

Answer (score 0):

Please, try changing of this line:

```
sText = "('" & rst!CityID & "','" & rst!City & "','0'),"
```

with:

```
If rst.EOF then
    sText = "('" & rst!CityID & "','" & rst!City & "','0');"
Else
    sText = "('" & rst!CityID & "','" & rst!City & "','0'),"
End If
```

Comment: The last comma in the last row.

Comment: @YvetteLee **Only** in the last row?

Comment: The best solution is a backspace and simple add ; but i can't. lol

Comment: @YvetteLee Try the adapted answer, please.

Comment: No, it is not working. it is looping but jumping always to ELSE.

Comment: @YvetteLee: Then, I would suggest you to change the logic of the text file building. I mean to create a string for each recordset line, as your code does right now. All them will be separated by `VbCrLf` (ending in this character) and finally the last two caracters ("," and `VbCrLf`) to be replaced with ";". And the string to be put at once at the end. In fact there will be three characters (VbCr and VbLf plus ","). Now I must leave my office, but if you do not understand what exactly I wanted to suggest, I can post a piece of code when I will be at home...

Comment: To make this work, appending `,` or `;` (and only that single character) must come **after** `rst.MoveNext`.